# What's the proper way to describe an associative object by SQLalchemy the declarative way

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm looking for a way to describe an associative object the declarative way. Beyond storing the foreign keys in the association table, I need to store information like the creation date of the association.

Today, my model looks like that :

```
# Define the User class
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    # Define User fields
    id = schema.Column(types.Integer(unsigned=True),
        schema.Sequence('users_seq_id', optional=True), primary_key=True)
    password = schema.Column(types.Unicode(64), nullable=False)

# Define the UserSubset class
class UserSubset(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'subsets'

    # Define UserSubset fields
    id = schema.Column(types.Integer(unsigned=True),
        schema.Sequence('subsets_seq_id', optional=True), primary_key=True)
    some_short_description = schema.Column(types.Unicode(50), nullable=False)

# Define the subset memberships table
subset_memberships = schema.Table('group_memberships', Base.metadata,
    schema.Column('user_id', types.Integer(unsigned=True), ForeignKey('users.id')),
    schema.Column('subset_id', types.Integer(unsigned=True), ForeignKey('subsets.id')),
    schema.Column('created', types.DateTime(), default=now, nullable=False),
)
```

Can I connect everything in an associative object ? Or should I change stop using the declarative way ?

Comment: Agh! I have been using SQLAlchemy and I hate it! I don't know what all the fuss is about with ORMs. All that Python is more grim that SQL bundled into a factory.

Comment: Probably. But the fact is : we need to make out application work regardless of the storage engine used. I don't want to have to rewrite every query each time we change the storage engine.

Comment: @Aiden: please take no offense, but if you are writing more code using SQLAlchemy than pure Python, you are likely using it wrong.

Comment: @voyager, most probably. And the factory statement was probably a bit OTT. I just find most ORM methods a bit dirty; Can't articulate it, just something wrong.

Comment: @Aiden: I can relate to that, I've found specially the Java canned ORMs are particularly cumbersome, but SQLAlchemy gives you lots of small stuff for free. I haven't yet come across a SQLAlchemy made Query that were a performance bottleneck, and it can be really shorter code. Of course you have to get used to some of its idioms first. Take a look at Django's ORM if you'd like to see some of the cool stuff that can come "for free" with a well built ORM. I guess the problem you are describing is something of a dissonance between how we conceive code and how we conceive relational databases.

Comment: @voyager, your dissonance statement is very true. I have a Mapped-object base class that uses DESC to map to attributes and a basic factory which gets/maps from queries. Simple, but it reacts to my changes in the DB automagically. You know what I mean, I know what I mean :P

Comment: @AidenBell Not sure what you think the problem is.  With ORM you get objects with methods instead of strings of sql in the code, which you need to pass tuples of values with. Python reflection allows objects and attributes to be discoverable without documentation, there is less context switching, you can pass kwargs instead of tuples. On top of this database reflection is quite awesome.  The only time I could possibly see SQLAlchemy being cumbersome is for very simple SQL queries/DB's, or if you know SQL and the database inside and out, but know little about Python and/or SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are using at the moment is just a Many-to-Many-relation. How to work with association objects is described in the [docs](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/mappers.html#association-object).

There is also an extension called [associationproxy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/reference/ext/associationproxy.html#associationproxy) which simplifies the relation.

Comment: Yep, I've noticed it. But since everything is made using the declarative syntax, is it the good way to use the mapper to create my association object ?
Or do I miss something ?

Comment: You should be able to mix them freely or use associationproxy in declarative syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [the manual](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/reference/ext/declarative.html#configuring-relations), configuring a one to many relation is really simple:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    addresses = relation("Address", backref="user")

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'addresses'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String(50))
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

[Many to many relations](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/reference/ext/declarative.html#configuring-many-to-many-relations) isn't much harder:

> There’s nothing special about many-to-many with declarative. The secondary argument to relation() still requires a Table object, not a declarative class. The Table should share the same MetaData object used by the declarative base:
>
> ```
>  keywords = Table('keywords', Base.metadata,
>                      Column('author_id', Integer, ForeignKey('authors.id')),
>                      Column('keyword_id', Integer, ForeignKey('keywords.id'))
>              )
>              
>  class Author(Base):
>      __tablename__ = 'authors'
>      id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
>      keywords = relation("Keyword", secondary=keywords)
> ```
>
> You should generally **not** map a class and also specify its table in a many-to-many relation, since the ORM may issue duplicate INSERT and DELETE statements.

Anyway, what you seem to be doing might be better served with [inheritance](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/reference/ext/declarative.html#inheritance-configuration). Of course, there can be complex table relations that will be a pathological case for the declarative way, but this doesn't seem to be one of them.

<sub>One more thing, code comments should state what the following code does ans why, not how it does it. Having a `# Define the User class` comment is almost like having a line of code saying `a = 1 # assing value 1 to variable "a"`.</sub>

Comment: Thank you. But as you can see, I don't want to describe a many-to-many declaration, but an association object.
I have some attributes beyond the two foreign keys in the association table, and as I can see in the manual, it's not the same as many-to-many relationships.

Comment: Docs reference here are quite old see http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html#many-to-many instead.